# R Generating multiple Excel files based on aggregated data

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on a small project on R where my objective is to create multiple Excel files per `Site` in my dataframe. The dataframe consists of comments from a survey, where each row represents a response for a given site. There a 10 columns in total, the first for the `Site` and the 9 others with comments per topic.

These comments columns can be grouped into the following blocks -

Block 1: **Overall** = Seating + Decor + Reception + Toilets

Block 2: **Comfort & Speed** = Comfort + Speed

Block 3: **Operations** = Efficiency + Courtesy + Responsiveness

The reproducible dataframe look like this

```
#Load libraries
 library(dplyr)
 library(xlsx)
 
#Reproducible Data Frame

df=data.frame(Site=c("Tokyo Harbor","Tokyo Harbor","Tokyo Harbor","Arlington","Arlington","Cairo Skyline","Cairo Skyline"),
       Seating=c("comfy never a problem to find","difficult","ease and quick","nobody to help","nice n comfy","old seats","nt bad"),
         Decor=c("very beautiful","i loved it!!!","nice","great","nice thanks","no response","yea nice"),
     Reception=c("always neat","I wasn't happy with the decor on this site","great!","immaculate","happy very helpful","","I wont bother again"),
       Toilets=c("well maintained","nicely managed","long queues could do better","","cleaner toilets needed!","no toilet roll in the mens loo","flush for god's sake!!!"),
       Comfort=c("very comfortable and heated","I felt like I was home","","couldn't be better","very nice and kush","not comment","fresh eyes needed"),
         Speed=c("rapid service","no delays ever got everything I needed on time","","","I have grown accustomed to the speed of service","machines","super duper quick"),
    Efficiency=c("very efficient, the servers were great","spot on","","I was quite disappointed in the efficiency","clockwork","parfait",""),
      Courtesy=c("Staff were very polite","smiling faces everywhere, loved it","very welcoming and kind","the hostess was a bit rude","trés impoli","noo",""),
Responsiveness=c("On the ball all the time","super quick whenever help was needed","","","","want more service like this",""))

#Transform all columns with empty cells to NAs

df[df==""]  <- NA
```

**My Objective**

For each site, create an Excel file with comments grouped into blocks (as defined above). Each Sheet in the Excel file represents one block, so there would be three sheets in total.

In more detail:

Step 1 - For each site, group comments together into three blocks, and filter out the comments.

Step 2 - Write Excel file with three sheets, each for a given block

I'd like the Excel files saved in the following format -

> COMMENTS_*SITENAME*_2017.xlsx

So for this `df` the desired output would be three Excel files, as there are three sites...

> COMMENTS_Tokyo Harbor_2017.xlsx
>
> COMMENTS_Arlington_2017.xlsx
>
> COMMENTS_Cairo Skyline_2017.xlsx

**My Attempt**

I started off by defining my blocks, which I later use to filter out the comments

```
###########################
#STEP 1: Define the blocks

#Block 1: Overall = Seating + Decor + Reception + Toilets
BlockOverall=c(names(df)[2],names(df)[3],names(df)[4],names(df)[5])

#Block 2: Comfort & Speed = Comfort + Speed
BlockComfortSpeed=c(names(df)[6],names(df)[7])

#Block 3: Operations = Efficiency + Courtesy + Responsiveness
BlockOps=c(names(df)[8],names(df)[9],names(df)[10])
```

Then I group comments based on these blocks, and filter out the data

```
###############################################
#STEP 2: Group comments based on defined blocks

#Group Overall
Data_Overall= df %>%
select(BlockOverall)

Data_Overall = Data_Overall %>%
do(.,data.frame(Comments_Overall=unlist(Data_Overall,use.names = F))) %>%
filter(complete.cases(.))

#Group Comfort & Speed
Data_ComfortSpeed= df %>%
select(BlockComfortSpeed)

Data_ComfortSpeed = Data_ComfortSpeed %>%
do(.,data.frame(Comments_ComfortSpeed=unlist(Data_ComfortSpeed,use.names = F))) %>%
filter(complete.cases(.))

#Group Operations
Data_Operations= df %>%
select(BlockOps)

Data_Operations = Data_Operations %>%
do(.,data.frame(Comments_Operations=unlist(Data_Operations,use.names = F))) 
%>%
filter(complete.cases(.))
```

And finally, I write the data to Excel

```
#Write each group to an individual tab in an Excel file

 library(xlsx)
 write.xlsx(Data_Overall,"Comments_Global_2017.xlsx",sheetName = 
'Overall',row.names = F) #Tab 1
 write.xlsx(Data_ComfortSpeed,"Comments_Global_2017.xlsx",sheetName = 
'Comfort_&_Speed',row.names = F,append = T) #Tab 2
 write.xlsx(Data_Operations,"Comments_Global_2017.xlsx",sheetName = 
'Operations',row.names = F,append = T) #Tab 3
```

On a global level,  this works fine. By I cannot figure out how to convert this to a `for` loop, that loops over all sites in the dataframe and generates a site-level Excel file.

Being a novice programmer, any pointers or suggestions will be highly valued!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `purrr` from the `tidyverse` you can avoid the for loop.

If you take your code above and wrap it into a basic function you can just iterate over the function for each site name using `purrr::map`.

### Your setup:

```
#Load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)
library(purrr)

#Reproducible Data Frame

df=data.frame(Site=c("Tokyo Harbor","Tokyo Harbor","Tokyo Harbor","Arlington","Arlington","Cairo Skyline","Cairo Skyline"),
              Seating=c("comfy never a problem to find","difficult","ease and quick","nobody to help","nice n comfy","old seats","nt bad"),
              Decor=c("very beautiful","i loved it!!!","nice","great","nice thanks","no response","yea nice"),
              Reception=c("always neat","I wasn't happy with the decor on this site","great!","immaculate","happy very helpful","","I wont bother again"),
              Toilets=c("well maintained","nicely managed","long queues could do better","","cleaner toilets needed!","no toilet roll in the mens loo","flush for god's sake!!!"),
              Comfort=c("very comfortable and heated","I felt like I was home","","couldn't be better","very nice and kush","not comment","fresh eyes needed"),
              Speed=c("rapid service","no delays ever got everything I needed on time","","","I have grown accustomed to the speed of service","machines","super duper quick"),
              Efficiency=c("very efficient, the servers were great","spot on","","I was quite disappointed in the efficiency","clockwork","parfait",""),
              Courtesy=c("Staff were very polite","smiling faces everywhere, loved it","very welcoming and kind","the hostess was a bit rude","trés impoli","noo",""),
              Responsiveness=c("On the ball all the time","super quick whenever help was needed","","","","want more service like this",""))

#Transform all columns with empty cells to NAs

df[df==""]  <- NA
```

### Your Steps in a function:

1. Take your dataframe and filter by argument site name
2. Perform all the steps you did above
3. Write site df to spreadsheet

### The Function:

```
export_site_data <- function(site.name){
  ###########################
  #STEP 0: filter by block site
  df <- df %>% filter(Site %in% site.name)


  ###########################
  #STEP 1: Define the blocks

  #Block 1: Overall = Seating + Decor + Reception + Toilets
  BlockOverall=c(names(df)[2],names(df)[3],names(df)[4],names(df)[5])

  #Block 2: Comfort & Speed = Comfort + Speed
  BlockComfortSpeed=c(names(df)[6],names(df)[7])

  #Block 3: Operations = Efficiency + Courtesy + Responsiveness
  BlockOps=c(names(df)[8],names(df)[9],names(df)[10])



  ###############################################
  #STEP 2: Group comments based on defined blocks

  #Group Overall
  Data_Overall= df %>%
    select(BlockOverall)

  Data_Overall = Data_Overall %>%
    do(.,data.frame(Comments_Overall=unlist(Data_Overall,use.names = F))) %>%
    filter(complete.cases(.))

  #Group Comfort & Speed
  Data_ComfortSpeed= df %>%
    select(BlockComfortSpeed)

  Data_ComfortSpeed = Data_ComfortSpeed %>%
    do(.,data.frame(Comments_ComfortSpeed=unlist(Data_ComfortSpeed,use.names = F))) %>%
    filter(complete.cases(.))

  #Group Operations
  Data_Operations= df %>%
    select(BlockOps)

  Data_Operations = Data_Operations %>%
    do(.,data.frame(Comments_Operations=unlist(Data_Operations,use.names = F))) %>%  filter(complete.cases(.))

  library(xlsx)
  write.xlsx(Data_Overall, paste0("Comments_",site.name,"_2017.xlsx"), sheetName = 
               'Overall',row.names = F) #Tab 1
  write.xlsx(Data_ComfortSpeed, paste0("Comments_",site.name,"_2017.xlsx"), sheetName = 
               'Comfort_&_Speed',row.names = F,append = T) #Tab 2
  write.xlsx(Data_Operations, paste0("Comments_",site.name,"_2017.xlsx"), sheetName = 
               'Operations',row.names = F,append = T) #Tab 3
}
```

### Use Map to iterate through site names

```
site.name <- unique(df$Site)
site.name %>% map(export_site_data )
```

### The results:

```
list.files(pattern = "Comments_")
[1] "Comments_Arlington_2017.xlsx"     "Comments_Cairo Skyline_2017.xlsx"
[3] "Comments_Tokyo Harbor_2017.xlsx"
```

Comment: Works well with the reproducible dataframe I provided, however when I test this out on another dataframe with the same structure but with more sites, the first few Excel files are generated fine and then I get this error:  Error in mapply(setCellValue, cells[seq_len(nrow(cells)), colIndex[ic]],  : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

Comment: Hm, you might check to see which site it's getting hung up on and see if you can walk through your process step by step for that site. If I had to guess, either `Data_Overall`, `Data_ComfortSpeed` , or `Data_Operations` has no rows causing one of the functions to send the error as it's looping through.

Comment: I think I figured it out, works fine now. I adapted the write.xlsx function with a custom write.xlsx function which factors in sheets with empty rows. Thanks for the help!